# Postgres - Force Drop Database With Replication Running

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to drop the database, but kept getting that I have active replication slot.

I tried to drop logical replication subscription.
I tried to disable it and drop it

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION aaa DISABLE;
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION aaa SET (slot_name = NONE);
```

I tried to terminate the backend pid and drop it but at the end nothing worked.

How can I just perform "drop the database no matter what"

Comment: Please give us the exact error message, not your interpretation of it.

Comment: Are you trying to drop it from the master side or from the replica side?

Comment: I got the following error when trying to drop the database.  ERROR:  database "aaa_db" is used by an active logical replication slot
DETAIL:  There is 1 active slot.
SQL state: 55006

I tried to drop the subscription, but it failed.  
Then I tried to drop the replication slot from the publisher side but that failed also.  I do not have the error message for those failures, but would like to know if it is possible to drop database even if it has running logical replication